# Juniper SSG5 Help!

Tags: juniper, ssg5

Newbie in firewall here. . .I need my trust zone to access the internet but the problem is I cant make it happen. So far, from the trust zone, I'm able to ping the IP's in the unstrust zone but I can't ping the IPs within the trust zone or bgroup0.

I can also use telnet inside the trust zone to the untrust zone.

Here is my configuration:

```
{
unset key protection enable
set clock timezone 0
set vrouter trust-vr sharable
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
unset auto-route-export
exit
set alg appleichat enable
unset alg appleichat re-assembly enable
set alg sctp enable
set auth-server "Local" id 0
set auth-server "Local" server-name "Local"
set auth default auth server "Local"
set auth radius accounting port 1646
set admin name "netscreen"
set admin password "I'm an idiot for including my password on a public site"
set admin auth web timeout 10
set admin auth dial-in timeout 3
set admin auth server "Local"
set admin format dos
set zone "Trust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Untrust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "DMZ" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "VLAN" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Untrust-Tun" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Trust" tcp-rst 
set zone "Untrust" block 
unset zone "Untrust" tcp-rst 
set zone "MGT" block 
unset zone "V1-Trust" tcp-rst 
unset zone "V1-Untrust" tcp-rst 
set zone "DMZ" tcp-rst 
unset zone "V1-DMZ" tcp-rst 
unset zone "VLAN" tcp-rst 
set zone "Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "Untrust" screen land
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen land
set interface "ethernet0/0" zone "Untrust"
set interface "ethernet0/1" zone "DMZ"
set interface "bgroup0" zone "Trust"
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/2
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/3
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/4
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/5
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/6
unset interface vlan1 ip
set interface ethernet0/0 ip 192.168.200.225/24
set interface ethernet0/0 route
set interface bgroup0 ip 192.168.201.1/24
set interface bgroup0 nat
set interface ethernet0/0 gateway 192.168.200.1
set interface "ethernet0/0" pmtu ipv4
set interface "bgroup0" pmtu ipv4
unset interface vlan1 bypass-others-ipsec
unset interface vlan1 bypass-non-ip
set interface ethernet0/0 ip manageable
set interface bgroup0 ip manageable
set interface ethernet0/0 manage ping
set interface ethernet0/0 manage ssh
set interface ethernet0/0 manage telnet
set interface ethernet0/0 manage snmp
set interface ethernet0/0 manage ssl
set interface ethernet0/0 manage web
set interface ethernet0/0 manage ident-reset
set interface bgroup0 manage mtrace
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server service
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server auto
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server ip 192.168.201.10 to 192.168.201.20 
unset interface bgroup0 dhcp server config next-server-ip
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" init "AT&F"
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" active
set interface "serial0/0" modem speed 115200
set interface "serial0/0" modem retry 3
set interface "serial0/0" modem interval 10
set interface "serial0/0" modem idle-time 10
set flow tcp-mss
unset flow tcp-syn-check
unset flow tcp-syn-bit-check
set flow reverse-route clear-text prefer
set flow reverse-route tunnel always
set pki authority default scep mode "auto"
set pki x509 default cert-path partial
set crypto-policy
exit
set ike respond-bad-spi 1
set ike ikev2 ike-sa-soft-lifetime 60
unset ike ikeid-enumeration
unset ike dos-protection
unset ipsec access-session enable
set ipsec access-session maximum 5000
set ipsec access-session upper-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session lower-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session dead-p2-sa-timeout 0
unset ipsec access-session log-error
unset ipsec access-session info-exch-connected
unset ipsec access-session use-error-log
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
exit
set url protocol websense
exit
set policy id 1 from "Trust" to "Untrust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit 
set policy id 1
exit
set policy id 2 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit 
set policy id 2
exit
set policy id 3 from "Trust" to "Trust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit 
set policy id 3
exit
set nsmgmt bulkcli reboot-timeout 60
set ssh version v2
set config lock timeout 5
unset license-key auto-update
set telnet client enable
set snmp port listen 161
set snmp port trap 162
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
unset add-default-route
exit
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
exit
 }
```

Comment: Tom may have been a little mean, but please do try to remove your passwords from configs.

Comment: I really need  help here I followed the config guide and I still end up with the same problem. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first thing is more of a suggestion than a fix -- don't put your interface in NAT mode.  Go to the interface and put it into route mode.  Then go to the Trust -> Untrust policy page, select your any/any/any policy, and click Advanced, and put the rule into Source Nat mode.  When you click apply, and save, then the icon for the rule should turn blue.  (Why do this?  Well it makes it clear on the policy page that NAT is happening.  It also gives you the flexibility to do non-NATing through the firewall should you desire.)

Second.  Your 'untrust' address is 192.168.200.x/24 -- that looks like a reserved IP.  Can you ping the firewall's untrust gateway of 192.168.200.1?  Are you sure the /24 is the correct mask size?  Can you set a system on the "untrust" network with those parameters and get connectivity to the internet?  Can you figure out what the next-hop IP is after the default gateway is, and get to that?

Third.  You don't seem to have DNS set as a DHCP option, so your DHCP clients don't get a DNS server.  Is that intentional?

Fourth.  You don't need policy 2 unless IPs from the "untrust" side will be initiating connections to the Trust side.  With policy 1, the traffic that flows back to the trust side is implied permitted as associated.

Fifth.  You shouldn't need the Trust -> Trust rule unless you have multiple security zones marked as Trust (which you don't).

Sixth.  You seem to be doing all your management via the untrust interface.  This might be what you want, but it looks backwards to me, permitting the untrust network access to your management.